# initializing a structure pointer - c

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, structure

Sorry if it is a too simple question. I was trying to compile some socket invoking code, and I had to use this

```
SOCKADDR_IN * sin;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

The problem is that I am told that I must initialize the pointer. (Is it necessary ?) Btw, how to initialize a structure pointer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to declare one on the stack instead of as a pointer. A pointer is just a memory address, not the actual instance of the object.

Just change your code to

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

And then when you need to use it, take the address of it like this: `&sin`

**Edit for original question answer**

To initialise a pointer if you really want to would be to do this:

```
SOCKADDR_IN* sin = (SOCKASSR_IN*)malloc(sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
....use sin....
free(sin);
```

This will allocate you memory on the heap with the size being set to the size of the SOCKADDR_IN struct. But as said before, this is unnecessary and generally should be avoided unless you need to use this structure outside of the current stack frame (function).

Comment: oh thanks I know about that, but I wanted to know if there is a specific way to initialize a struct pointer ?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer that question

Comment: thank you, tell me if I am wrong but when I use & to retrieve the local variable and use it in an other function, I can control its value when <i get back to the first function that declared it. So what is the advantage to use & than allocating dynamically memory  ? I suppose it is a speed issue, isn't it ?

Comment: @Salgar It'd be better practice [not to cast the return from malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).  It'd also arguably be slightly more future proof if you allocated `sizeof(*sin)` bytes (its equivalent to `sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)` now but will keep working if you ever change the type of `sin` in future)

Comment: @Newben Stack allocation is typically much faster than `malloc`.  More importantly, you have to remember to call `free` for dynamically allocated memory; variables on the stack have their storage reclaimed automatically when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary that you allocate memory for a `SOCKADDR_IN` instance.  You don't have to create a pointer though; you could allocate it on the stack instead

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

then use the address operator `&` if you want to pass `sin` to a function that expects a `SOCKADDR_IN*`

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
....
function_using_socket_pointer(&sin);
```

Update: it seems you want to use a dynamically allocated pointer.  You can do this using

```
SOCKADDR_IN* sin = malloc(sizeof(*sin));
if (sin == NULL) {
    /* insert oom handling here */
}
sin.sin_addr.s_addr    = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
....
free(sin);
```

Comment: oh thanks I know about that, but I wanted to know if there is a specific way to initialize a struct pointer ?